# Cannot import name 'Context" from 'django.template.base' when using django-social-widgets

Tags: django

When trying to include django-social-widget on Django 3.2.4, I encountered an error:

```
 File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'social_widgets.templatetags.social_widget
s': cannot import name 'Context' from 'django.template.base' (C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that app hasn't been touched since they [introduced django 2.2 support](https://github.com/creafz/django-social-widgets/commits/master). So you've got 2 choices;

- Downgrade to django 2.2
- Fork the repo and bring support for v3 (then submit a PR or install from your fork)

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced the same problem but if you use django-social-widgets version 0.5.0, then you can go to ...\site-packages\social_widgets\templatetags\social_widgets.py and then remove ",Context" from line 6. this solved my problem.Hope this may solve your problem too.

[image: (image) what to delete]